# MaaS fails to download the boot images

Tags: maas

I cant get MaaS to download the boot images

when i run

```
maas root node-groups import-boot-images
```

all I get is

```
Import of boot images started on all cluster controllers
```

and I don't get any images, same goes for the web ui.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The command given on the MAAS documentation did not work out for me as well, so I ran:

```
sudo maas-import-pxe-files
```

Also run an update and reboot your machine afterwards, MAAS should then find the imported boot images.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```